# Remove Json Array String, Left the Value Only in Java Spring

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, spring-boot

I want to remove the string "Date" in String Json Array Java Spring
here is the respon

```
    {
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "Date": "2021/02/12"
        },
        {
            "Date": "2021/05/13"
        },
    ]
}
```

i want to change the respon json array to this model :

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": [
        "2021-02-12",
        "2021-05-13"
    ]
}
```

and the last here is my code for getting the respon in json:

```
ArrayList<ResponGetHoliday> res = new ArrayList<ResponGetHoliday>();
res.addAll((Collection<? extends ResponGetHoliday>)
           simulationRepository.getHoliday(Tahun));
responseArray.setData(res);
responseArray.setMessage("OK");
```

heres my responGetHoliday or model data :

```
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<String> data = null;

    public ResponGetHoliday() {
    }

    public ResponGetHoliday(List<String> data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

I'm using jdbcTemplate for EXEC my stored procedure.

Here is the response returned by my stored procedure:

```
Date
---------
2021/02/12
2021/05/13
```

And this is how I call the stored procedure from jdbcTemplate:

```
  final String SELECT_QUERY_getDate = "exec spGetDate ?";
  public List<Map<String, Object>> getHoliday(String Year) {
    return jdbcTemplateThree.queryForList(SELECT_QUERY_getDate, Year);
  }
```

Comment: Can you please add `ResponGetHoliday` to your question? Thanks.

Comment: @JoãoDias done, please check again

Comment: Wait, `ResponGetHoliday` already has a `List<String>` which is exactly what you want. So my question is, from where is your first JSON coming from?

Comment: im using jdbcTemplate for calling the Store Procedure, which is return the value array of "Date" @JoãoDias i

Comment: i have been edited my question please take a look maybe it will help @JoãoDias

Comment: the repository should return ResponGetHoliday - you can convert there template result as List<String>, and create new ResponGetHoliday(list_of_dates)

Comment: What is the type of `responseArray`? Can you add that class as well to the question? Please strive to provide all the relevant information, and not simply snippets of your code. Otherwise we will keep going and ask you for additional information. Thanks!